# How to protect a process from crash by modify a dynamic library it has loaded in linux?

Tags: linux, crash

I have a process that loads a dynamic library when it starts(dlopen/dlsym etc), and I can 
send some message to it while it's running to let the process unload the previous .so(dlclose) and load
a new one.

Here the question becomes, while the process is running, if I transfer a new .so using nc like:

```
nc -l 9999 > mylibrary.so
```

If I give nc the same filename which has been loaded by the process, then the process got segv
immediately after the above command being executed.

Another case that will cause process crash is when I package the .so file into an rpm package and
the .so file in the rpm is the same, then yum update XXX will cause the process crash too.

I've been told that there's a way to load the .so file into memory to avoid the problem, but failed
to find any resource related to it.

Any thoughts will be thankful.

Comment: A wild guess: Have you tried using `dlopen()` with the `RTLD_NOW` flag?

Comment: here's the option I used in dlopen: RTLD_NOW | RTLD_LOCAL.

Comment: This is a very curious question... I have no idea, but if I were to guess, I imagine it could be that the loader just memory-maps the shared object file, so you wouldn't be allowed to overwrite it. If that were the case (as you could find out with `strace`), then the only option might be to make a local copy before using `dlopen()`.

Comment: Indeed dlopen calls mmap. I found a link illustrating how to load a dll from memory under windows: http://www.joachim-bauch.de/tutorials/loading-a-dll-from-memory/ . I'm just curious if there is such a trick in linux world.